# Find bridge days in a list of days

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I want to find "bridge days" from a list of days. The list:

```
days = [
 %{value: ~D[2017-04-01], categories: ["weekend"]},
 %{value: ~D[2017-04-02], categories: ["weekend"]},
 %{value: ~D[2017-04-03], categories: []},
 %{value: ~D[2017-04-04], categories: []},
 ...
 %{value: ~D[2017-04-13], categories: ["bank holiday"]},
 %{value: ~D[2017-04-14], categories: ["bank holiday"]},
 %{value: ~D[2017-04-15], categories: ["weekend"]},
 %{value: ~D[2017-04-16], categories: ["weekend", "bank holiday"]},
 ... ]
```

The month as rendered on the webpage:

[image: Screenshot of April in the calendar]

Somebody who wants to maximize his/her vacation days would take a vacation on the 10th, 11th and 12th because that would result in a 10 day vacation (8th - 17th) for an investment of just 3 vacation days.

I want to write a function `bridge_days(days, number_of_invested_vacation_days)` which results in a list of those three days `[~D[2017-04-10], ~D[2017-04-11], ~D[2017-04-12]]` when called with `bridge_days(days, 3)`. 3 being the number of invested vacation days.

An other month example:

[image: Screenshot of Mai in the calendar]

`bridge_days(days, 1)` would result in `[~D[2017-05-26]]` because an investment of 1 vacation day results in 4 days of vacation.

Actually `bridge_days/2` would often result in a list of lists because many times there are multiple options.

My approach is to loop through the list, comparing +1 and -1 of each day. The problem is that it takes for ever to do.

Is there a more clever way than using this kind of brute force to solve this problem?

Comment: what no attempt as coding?

Comment: @GavinBrelstaff The question is less "how do I do this" and more "I have a working solution, but I am looking for a better algorithm".

Comment: @JustinWood I have the feeling that there might be a "Elixir-Like" solution for the given problem which I haven't found. I'm searching for an a) elegant and b) fast solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an idea for a bruteforce `O(n^2)` algorithm that should be fairly fast for short lists. I'm going to use a simplified representation of the days: a list of booleans. `true` means it's a holiday, `false` means it's not. Here's how the algorithm works:

We consider every index of the list as a possible start day.

For each index, we find the number of days we could've had with the given number of vacations. For this, we slice off the old days, then using `reduce_while`, keep taking the days until we've used all vacations (or the list ends). We also track the number of holidays encountered.

We use `Enum.max_by` to apply the above step on each day and get back the best day to start the vacation. You can get the actual vacation days by iterating from this index.

```
defmodule A do
  def go(days, vacation) do
    0..(length(days) - 1)
    |> Enum.max_by(fn from ->
      days |> Enum.drop(from) |> Enum.reduce_while({0, 0}, fn holiday?, {collected, taken} ->
        cond do
          # If it's a holiday, we've collected one day without consuming more vacations.
          holiday? -> {:cont, {collected + 1, taken}}
          # If we've taken all vacations possible, we halt.
          vacation == taken -> {:halt, {collected, taken}}
          # Otherwise, we collect another day and also consume one vacation day.
          true -> {:cont, {collected + 1, taken + 1}}
        end
      end)
      |> elem(0)
    end)
  end
end

t = true
f = false
# April from your screenshot.
days = [t, t, f, f, f, f, f, t, t, f, f, f, t, t, t, t, t, f, f, f, f, t, t, f, f, f, f, f, t, t]
IO.inspect A.go(days, 3)
```

Output:

```
7
```

So the 8th day of the month is the best day to start the vacation, which matches your description.

Answer (score 1):

You have requested for an algorithm. I believe that the key point to this is to collapse your days to a list of amount of "on-duty/off-duty" days. For April, this would correspond to:

```
collapsed_days = [
  {:off, 2}, 
  {:on, 5}, {:off, 2}, 
  {:on, 3}, {:off, 5}, 
  {:on, 4}, {:off, 2}, 
  {:on, 5}, {:off, 2}
]
```

Now your `function` bridge days would be as follows:
`bridge_days(collapsed_days, 3)`

In this `function`, you do the following:

- Search for the smallest amount of on-duty days, in this case `{:on, 3}`
- Apply as many vacation days accordingly, so it becomes: `{:off, 3}`
- Collapse the resulting consecutive `{:off, _}` days, so the list becomes:

  [
    {:off, 2}, 
    {:on, 5}, {:off, 10}, 
    {:on, 4}, {:off, 2}, 
    {:on, 5}, {:off, 2}
  ]
- In the case that you have more vacation days to apply, then tag them along accordingly. for instance `bridge_days(collapsed_days, 5)`, in addition to `{:off, 10}`, you also need to create an `{:off, 2}` by taking those days immediately before or after `{:off, 10}`.
- In the case that you have less vacation days available than the smallest `{:on, _}` amount, then apply as many as you can.

I believe that this should always result in the most optimal solution, however I can be wrong as I haven't gone out of my way to mathematically proof this to be the case. If you cannot see how to mathematically proof this, then try to proof it through exhaustion, by testing all edge cases.

As you need to return the exact `dates` as opposed to a simple number, it may be best to work with triplets: `{:off, 2, [~D[2017-04-01], ~D[2017-04-02]]}` instead, and merge your lists accordingly.

Kindly provide feedback in the comments in the case you find an edge case that would break this approach.